# how newDate() will work if client country changes from server country

Tags: date, server, client

I am working on a project where client side works on angular server and all back-end works on tomcat server. Now all my concern is about `dln.setMetaSuperAdminDateCreated(new Date());`.
everywhere I am inserting date in system, I am Just Using Date object which inserts current system date.
what date will get inserted if my client sitting in some other country and trying to insert some data into system.

Comment: This is JavaScript-/Typescript-Code, right? Then it will use the local time, that depending on the Backend-Persistence-System, converts it to utc-Time, or not... if you want always the local time to be stored, you could convert it to UTC, but this leaves new issues. Treating Date in JavaScript is one of the biggest issues of this languages.

Comment: dln.setMetaSuperAdminDateCreated(new Date()); is from server side, means java code in back_end

Comment: You should edit your question and specify programming language(s) and also add language tag(s).

Comment: If it’s Backend code, it’s always the same time, but not related to client timezone.